# <td> click not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried following lines of code like

```
                  $(".datepicker .day").click(function(){
                     var dob = $("#dobfield").val().trim();
                     var calculatedAge = GetAge(dob);

                    if(calculatedAge < 0)
                        $("#age").val("");

                    else if(!isNaN(calculatedAge))
                        $("#age").val(calculatedAge);
                 });
```

In html

```
          <div class="datepicker">
           ...
             <table>
              ...
               <tr>
                 ...
                   <td class="day"> 12</td>
```

I am trying to add age dynamically to the textbox age. The .datepicker .day click event is not getting fired.
Please help me !!!

Comment: Can you add codepen demo?

Comment: Seems to work fine. Maybe your table cell doesn't exist at the time you add the click event?

Comment: Are the cells added dynamically or are they available on page load?

Comment: No this is not available on page load... datepicker gets visible when dobfield textbox is clicked

Comment: use `$(document).on('click','.datepicker .day', function(){});` if the content is dynamically generated

Comment: So date picker interface comes and you can select date properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It seems to work fine wrap your code in `$(document).ready` function. Below is demo of working code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datepicker .day").click(function() {
    var dob = $("#dobfield").val().trim();
    console.log(dob)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="datepicker">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="day"> 12 </td>
      <td><input id="dobfield" value="56" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: it is already wrapped in document ready function in my actual code

Comment: then there might be some other error can you share your console. And wpould be great if you can create a demo replicating your issue.

Comment: there is no error message in console because it is not getting triggered

Comment: *Note:* please don't use `$(document).ready(function() {` (it's deprecated), use `$(function() {` instead. See: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Nida then it might help you can replicate the issue on fiddle or plnkr.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) function to listen to the click event of dynamically added table cells by attaching it to the `.datepicker` div.

If the `.datepicker` div is generated dynamically you'll have to add the on function to the document itself.

e.g.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".datepicker .day", function() {
  console.log("clicked");
});

// dynamically adding the datepicker.
$("#container").append("<div class='datepicker'><table><tr><td class='day'>12</td></tr></table></div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry it is does not work... should i wrap it in document ready function

Comment: I've updated to handle adding of the datepicker div dynamically. Does the new code work?

Comment: Which date picker control are you using?

Comment: can u please suggest me similar solution for display : none